# Showing the Heisenberg group admits the presentation $\langle A, B, C\mid AC=CA, BC=CB, ABA^{-1}B^{-1}=C\rangle.$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-presentation

> Consider the subset of $SL_3(\Bbb Z)$ consisting of matrices of the form
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & a & c\\ 
> 0 & 1 & b \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> for $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z$.
>
> I need to show that it admits the presentation:
>
> $$\langle A, B, C\mid AC=CA, BC=CB, ABA^{-1}B^{-1}=C\rangle.$$

I am not sure what exactly I need to show. I tried to follow the definition given in class, but didn't really understand it.

> **Definition 1.36:** Let $G$ be a group and $S$ a generating set. Let $R\subseteq F(S)$. Denote by $\pi$ the morphism $F(S)\to G$. We say that $G$ admits the presentation $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ if $R$ normally generates $\ker \pi$, that is, if $\ker\pi$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing $R$.
>
> **Remark 1.38:** We can also build a group with any presentation we choose: given a set $S$ and a set $R$ of words in $S$, the quotient $F(S)/\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ obviously admits the presentation $\langle S\mid R\rangle$. Note that this is a way to specify a group algebraically, not geometrically.

Comment: Here's the steps. (1) Choose the correct matrices $A,B,C$ of the form given. (2) Prove the three equations given in the presentation. (3) Prove that any equation in the letters $A,B,C$ and their inverses that holds in the group may be derived formally from the three equations given. How far have you gotten?

Comment: I have choose the correct matices A,B,C and showed that the subgroup is generated by them. I have also checked that these matrices A,B,C meets the three equations that are given.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your step (3). Can you please provide some more details?

Comment: That's the hard part! For example, I'm sure your choice of $A,B,C$ satisfies the equation $A C B C^{-1} A^{-1} B^{-1} = C$; and you can see that this equation is a consequence of the 2nd and 3rd equations in the presentation, by making a substitution. You have to prove that for every one of the infinitely many equations in the symbols $A,B,C,A^{-1},B^{-1},C^{-1}$ that holds in the group, that equation is a consequence of the three equations given, by a sequence of substitutions.

Comment: The way I would do this is to show, using the relations of the presentation, that every element in the group defined by the presentation can be represented by a word of the form $A^iB^jC^k$ for $i,j,k \in {\mathbb Z}$. Then show that these elements correspond to distinct elements of the Heisenberg group. So we have an isomorphism between the two groups.

Comment: OK
So I Set X={A,B,C} and consider F(X) of X
There is a homomorphisim  phi:F(X)->H

Do I need to show now that R={ACA^-1C^-1,BCB^-1C^-1,....} is a normal subgroup of Ker(phi)

Comment: Or use that the Heisenberg group is semidirect product of $Z^2$ and $Z$, where the rank 2 subgroup is normal.

Comment: I am confused here. Is my way of doing this ok?  because I couldn't prove that R is a normal subgroup of ker(phi)

Comment: All of these ways are equivalent, in particular: the general criterion I stated; the special criterion for this particular group that Derek Holt stated; and the statement that the subgroup normally generated by the relators $R$ is equal to $\ker(\phi)$. So once you've proved one of them is true, the others follow.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, how would that semidirect product form of the Heisenberg group help?